# Plotly bar chart value labels in wrong format

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I want to create a bar chart with Plotly express and label each bar with its corresponding value. However, for absolute values of <1, the format of the value labels is in thousands, i.e. the label is "-200m" instead of "-0.2".

How can I change to formatting of the value labels to be the same, i.e. in the 10^0 format, for all data points?

My current chart looks like this, and I want the value label under the bar of Gujarat to be "-0.2" instead of "-200m".

[Current chart, see link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiHme.png)

Thank you very much!

Here is the code to create the chart:

```
import plotly.express as px


states = ["Andhra Pradesh", "Gujarat", "Tamil Nadu", "Rajasthan"]
delta_gdp = [-1.4, -0.2, 3.1, 4.0]

d = {'state':states,'delta_gdp':delta_gdp}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig = px.bar(df, x='state', y='delta_gdp', text_auto=".2s", title = "Percentage difference in GDP")
fig.update_traces(textfont_size=14, textangle=0, textposition="outside", cliponaxis=False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Try this: `fig = px.bar(df, x='state', y='delta_gdp', text_auto='.2', title="Percentage difference in GDP")
`